# Promise on forEach loop which contains promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, async-await

I have nested forEach loops out of which one of them contains another await call. I want my function doSomething to be executed only after the nested loop is done. As of now doSomething() gets executed first.

```
    entity.forEach(function (dataItem) {
        userParams.forEach(async function (userParamItem) {
                const Marks = await _fetchMark(req, dataItem.MKTUNITID);
                //do some manipulation to Marks

            }

        }
    });
});
```

doSomething();

Comment: I assume doSomething(); should be part of the code-block as the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to use awaits inside a forEach (or any iterator loop; for, while, array-methods), I like to create a little array where I store the promises that are made.

I'll type out an example. I have a list of 10 urls I want to run a fetch towards, and store the results before running `doSomething()`. My `runFetch()`-function is asynchronous, and thus by default (unless I await it) returns a promise. After iterating, I will await ALL the promises at the same time, so they can run in parallell, but still wait for the slowest one.

```js
const urls = [...] // my urls
const promises = []

for (const url of urls) {
    promises.push( runFetch(url) )
}

const results = await Promise.all(promises)

//now that all my fetches are done, I can continue.
doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

*forEach* can be bit tricky in such situations, you can simply use *for* loops instead as
they will not jump to next item until all promises are not resolved

```
for(i =0; i < entity.length; i++) 
{
    let dataItem = entity[i]
    for(j =0; j < userParams.length; j++)
    {
        
        let userParamItem = userParams[i]
        const Marks = await _fetchMark(req, dataItem.MKTUNITID);
        //do some manipulation to Marks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does this because forEach is not promise-aware. It cannot support async and await so you cannot use await in forEach. Instead, use a `for...of` loop:

```
for(const dataItem of entity) {
    for(const userParamItem of userParams) {
            const Marks = await _fetchMark(req, dataItem.MKTUNITID);
            //do some manipulation to Marks
        }
    }
});
doSomething();
```

This way the nested loops will execute first and `doSomething()` last.

Here is a nice post if you wanna learn more:
https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/